React Native Expo Error: _configPlugins.Updates.getRuntimeVersion is not a function
I'm developing a React Native app using Expo, and I recently encountered a runtime error that seems to be related to the Expo environment, as I haven't made any changes to my code recently. The error is:
TypeError: _configPlugins.Updates.getRuntimeVersion is not a function
This issue started occurring without any recent updates to my codebase, suggesting it might be related to some changes in the environment. Here are some details about my setup:
Expo version:6.3.10
React Native version: "0.72.10",
I've cleared the node modules and cache using:
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf .expo
create new dev build
npm install
I've reinstalled the Expo CLI
None of these steps have resolved the issue. The function in question seems to be related to Expo's Updates module. I'm not sure if this is a version compatibility issue or if the function has been deprecated or replaced.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any suggestions on how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated!
